# Meaning of get a first class

Tags: sentence-meaning

In the sentence

> I am sure Helen will **get a first class**.

What is the meaning of **get a first class** in this case. Does it mean  **will achieve the first position** but I have never heard this.

Comment: Where did you hear or read this sentence? I know a possible answer, but it depends on the context.

Comment: It's an example sentence in an English language learning web site called "Kids World Fun".

Comment: Barring context (because we don't have *first class degrees* in the Canadian school system), if that's all I heard, I would associate it with a ticket. (A first-class train ticket or plane ticket.)

Answer (score 2):

Probably a very good grade of university degree. In the British education system, university degrees are, in descending order of merit:

First-class honours (1st, 'a first' or a 'first class'), the highest honours classification - indicates high academic achievement.

Upper second-class honours (a 2.1, a 'two-one')

Lower second-class honours (a 2.2, a 'two-two')

Third-class honours (a 3rd, a 'third')

Ordinary degree (a pass)

British honours degrees are sometimes considered equivalent (by British sources) to a US master's degree, with the US bachelor's degree being equivalent to a British pass degree, due to the much higher degree of specialisation in the UK.